# qcow2: Safe to use guestfish zerofree option on ext4 on top of LVM?

Tags: lvm, kvm-virtualization, ext4, qcow2

Is it safe to use [guestfish's zerofree option](http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html#zerofree) on ext4 which is inside an LVM volume? If not, what is the best approach - rebooting (inside the VM) into recovery mode and using the regular [zerofree utility](http://intgat.tigress.co.uk/rmy/uml/index.html)? I am having trouble finding any references online to using these two tools with LVMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should "just work".

There is more detail about the problem here:
https://www.redhat.com/archives/libguestfs/2011-September/thread.html#00007